# Storing (or passing) an Element/TableCell reference during a server-client round-trip

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-docs, google-docs-api

I'm trying to make a modal popup that does some work on a given table cell within a Google Doc using HTMLService and GAS.

The popup works and in general I can pass data from the server script to the client script and back.  The piece of data I can't seem to pass is **which table cell the cursor was at when the popup was opened**.

Approach 1: If I pass it directly to client and back, the reference is broken, because it's `null` by the time it gets to the client.  I can pass the cell's contents just fine in the exact same context, so strings work, it's just the fact that it's a cell reference.  (Makes sense enough.)

Approach 2: If I store the TableCell reference in a global variable on the server side, I get `Cannot call method "getText" of undefined`--the reference is undefined after the first round trip.  (I guess the server script gets reloaded entirely in that time.)

Approach 3: If I use CacheService.getUserCache() on the client side, when I try to get my cached TableCell object, it seems disconnected from the one I had set, because I get the heretofore unGoogleable error `Cannot find function getText in object TableCell.`

```
// server, before popup is opened:
cache.put('cell_currently_being_edited', active_doc.getCursor().getElement().getParent());

// popup client calls server function like so:
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(load_content).get_starting_content();

// server, where the above error occurs:

function get_starting_content() {
    var cell_currently_being_edited = cache.get('cell_currently_being_edited');
    return cell_currently_being_edited.getText();
}
```

If cells had some sort of fixed ID value I could pass, that could work...

I would do it based on the text in the cell, but I hope that's not the only option, because cell text in general (and yes, in this specific context too) may not be unique, so after the round trip I may end up replacing text in some other cell than the cursor was in when the user activates the popup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Solution:

- You could use the cell index as unique identifier to pass the RC string back and  forth between client and server as string values are legal.
- Use Properties/Cache Service to store RC Index information as string for future retrieval in Server, If needed.

#### Sample Script:

```
function getRCTIndexOfTable(tableCell) {
  var tableRow = tableCell.getParentRow();
  var table = tableRow.getParentTable();
  var column = tableRow.getChildIndex(tableCell);
  var row = table.getChildIndex(tableRow);
  var body = table.getParent().asBody();
  var tableId = body.getChildIndex(table);
  return 'R' + row + 'C' + column + 'T' + tableId;
}

function main() {
  var active_doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var activeTableCell = active_doc
    .getCursor()
    .getElement()
    .getParent()
    .asTableCell();
  Logger.log(getRCTIndexOfTable(activeTableCell));
}
```

#### References:

- [TableCell](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/table-cell)
- [TableCell from RCIndex](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/table#getCell(Integer,Integer))
- [Legal Values](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication#parameters_and_return_values)
- [PropertiesService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties-service#getScriptProperties())
- [CacheService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/cache/cache-service)

Comment: This looks like it should work, provided there's only one table in the doc.  But in my case that should be something that's fine to stick to.  Thanks also for the Legal Values reference--that explains why my direct cache attempt wasn't working.

Comment: It doesn't store which table to call `getCell()` on...unless there's a similar way of IDing a table that we could layer onto this.

Comment: Cool, I edited your answer to include this, and accepted it.  Thanks very much!  :)

Answer (score 0):

Since the other answer (even after modifying the code) focused on the "saving" half of the problem, I thought I would share code that includes how to load the reference afterwards to complete the round trip:

```
// save

var table_cell = active_doc.getCursor().getElement().getParent();
var table_row = table_cell.getParentRow();
var table = table_row.getParentTable();
var column_index = table_row.getChildIndex(table_cell);
var table_index = active_doc.getBody().getChildIndex(table);
var row_index = table.getChildIndex(table_row);
cache.put('table_currently_being_edited', table_index);
cache.put('row_currently_being_edited', row_index);
cache.put('column_currently_being_edited', column_index);

// load

function get_cell_currently_being_edited() {
    var table_index = cache.get('table_currently_being_edited');  
    var row_index = cache.get('row_currently_being_edited');
    var column_index = cache.get('column_currently_being_edited');
    return active_doc.getBody().getChild(table_index).getCell(row_index, column_index);  
}
```